# Take EF Model and Convert it to Datatable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datatable

I have a EF core model that I need to convert to a data table but I don't want to manually map it my self if possible.

I found this code in a stack answer

```
 private static DataTable CreateDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            var properties = type.GetProperties();

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
            {

                dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
            }

            foreach (T entity in list)
            {
                object[] values = new object[properties.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity);
                }

                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

however I have properties that of course reference other classes and I think they are being picked up as I get an error like this.

```
The type of column 'Category' is not supported.  The type is 'Category'
```

Comment: How do you want class types to be converted?

Comment: What if a property value is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

foreach (PropertyInfo info in type.GetProperties())
{
    if (info.PropertyType.IsValueType || info.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
         dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
         properties.Add(info);
    }
}
foreach (T entity in list)
{
     int i = 0;
     object[] values = new object[properties.Count];
     foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
     {
         values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity);
         i++;
     }

     dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
}
```

This same foreach you can use on the properties, so remove the for loop..

Comment: So you mean remove the foreach loop and use this same foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `DbContext` extension method I wrote that skips over navigations and computed columns and also applies type mapping conversions. This should be suitable for plugging directly into a bulk insert:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ConvertEntitiesToDataTable<T>(this DbContext @this, IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
    {
        var entityType = @this.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));

        // these aren't columns in the table and can therefore be skipped
        var navigations = entityType?.GetNavigations()
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToHashSet()
            ?? new HashSet<string>();

        // we just want to skip any computed columns
        var computedColumns = entityType?.GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetComputedColumnSql() is not null)
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToHashSet()
            ?? new HashSet<string>();

        // for properties that are stored as a different DB type than their CLR type (like enums stored as strings)
        var conversions = entityType?.GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetTypeMapping().Converter is not null)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetTypeMapping().Converter!)
            ?? new Dictionary<string, ValueConverter>();

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(x => !navigations.Contains(x.Name))
            .Where(x => !computedColumns.Contains(x.Name))
            .ToArray();

        PropertyInfo[] array = properties;

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in array)
        {
            ColumnAttribute? customAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();
            string name = propertyInfo.Name;
            if (customAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customAttribute.Name))
            {
                name = customAttribute.Name;
            }

            var columnType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;

            if (conversions.TryGetValue(propertyInfo.Name, out var conversion))
            {
                columnType = conversion.ProviderClrType;
            }

            dataTable.Columns.Add(name, columnType);
        }

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            object?[] array2 = new object[properties.Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < properties.Length; j++)
            {

                var propValue = properties[j].GetValue(item, null);

                if (conversions.TryGetValue(properties[j].Name, out var conversion))
                {
                    propValue = conversion.ConvertToProvider(propValue);
                }

                array2[j] = propValue;
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(array2);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```